# Is there any way to use send_keys on numeric input on python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python and selenium. When I enter number password(like 1234), It works well. But enter password with send_keys on python, 'You can only enter numbers' error appear. It's because of string of send_keys. How can I use send_keys with integer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the problem, but why don't you use this? (Considering, that 1234 is the password).

```
send_keys("1234")
```

`send_keys()` is a function that requires a string as input.

Comment: That also doesn't work. Website said You can only enter numbers.